# how to open each post using modal in laravel 8

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-8, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

When I click on a post, it fetches post.blade.php and comment.blade.php and runs it in bootstrap modal.

The following issues exist while processing the current job

1. Include error
   I just made a modal connection and tried @include('post.blade.php') in it.
   Error thrown because there is no $post variable used in the file

What I want to make is to call post.blade.php and comment.blade.php by passing the $post->id value as a parameter when clicking the post title to get data.

content.blade.php

```
  <a href="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#open_post_modal">

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="open_post_modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                {{--            <div class="modal-header">--}}
                {{--                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>--}}
                {{--                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>--}}
                {{--            </div>--}}
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @include('layouts.post')
                    {{--                @extends('layouts.post')--}}
{{--                    @extends('layouts.post')--}}
{{--                    @extends('layouts.comment')--}}
                </div>
                {{--            <div class="modal-footer">--}}
                {{--                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>--}}
                {{--                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>--}}
                {{--            </div>--}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

postcontroller

```
    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::with('channel')
            ->withCount('comments')
            ->with('likes')
            ->with('user')
            ->where('posts.id', '=', $id)
//            ->get()
            ->first();

        $comments = Comment::where('postID', '=', $id)
            ->with('user')
            ->with('likes')
            ->orderBy('group', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('order', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('depth', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

How can i solve this problem ?

[image]

[image]

======================= EDIT ===============

A page showing a list of posts ( index.blade.php )

The above page does not have the data of each post.

I wrote that the modal was connected to the content I wrote before editing.

Can I open it in bootstrap modal when a post is clicked?
If it is possible to open modally,  how can I do it?

Comment: Can your share Stack Trace for your error? It'd be useful to find an solution for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your, Routes/web.php is where you need pass your class through to a blade view.

```
Route::get('/content/{id}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->where(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
```

In your controller, you would then specify your return, in this case it would be a view

```
return view('content', ['data' => $data]);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
When I click the modal, do I have to call a href="javascript:functionName()" like this? How can I pass data to the modal after calling it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Stack Trace screenshot, you've attached I think
You didn't pass your `$post` data to your `blade.php` from the controller.

check your code what you missed in there :)

Comment: Yes
That part seems to be the part that keeps getting blocked.

I know my question is wrong
I will completely revise the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Before posting the question, I solved the problem as written below.

** Problem.
When I clicked on a post, a bootstrap modal opened and I had to put data from the controller in it.

** Process.
content.blade.php

```
<a href="" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-post-id="{{ $post->id }}" data-bs-target="#open_post_modal">

 var open_post_modal = document.getElementById('open_post_modal')
    open_post_modal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        // Button that triggered the modal
        var button = event.relatedTarget;
        // Extract info from data-bs-* attributes
        var postID = button.getAttribute('data-bs-post-id');
        // postID = JSON.parse(post);

        // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here
        // and then do the updating in a callback.
        // Update the modal's content.
        // var modalBody = open_post_modal.querySelector('.modal-content');
        var modalBody = $(".modal-content");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/post/'+postID,
            type: 'get',
            // data: {
            // 'type': type,
            // },
            success: function(data) {
                // modalBody.innerHTML = data;
                modalBody.html(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })

    })
```

PostController.php

```
    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::with('channel')
            ->withCount('comments')
            ->with('likes')
            ->with('user')
            ->where('posts.id', '=', $id)
//            ->get()
            ->first();

        $comments = Comment::where('postID', '=', $id)
            ->with('user')
            ->with('likes')
            ->orderBy('group', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('order', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('depth', 'asc')
            ->get();

        return view('post.show', compact('post', 'comments'));
    }
```